# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^0 \big(\log(1-e^{x^3})\big)^{1/3}~dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> How can I evaluate
> $$\int_{-\infty}^0 \left(\log \left(1-e^{x^3} \right)\right)^{1/3}~dx$$

I tried substitution, integration by parts and partial fractions.

A comment below suggests the answer is in the form of fractional derivatives of the beta function. I'm interested in the verification of this.

Comment: Your title and body would suggest two different questions

Comment: You should show your work at solving the problem.

Comment: I stated what I tried...

Comment: Sometimes you just don't know how to solve a problem to be honest.

Comment: $Hint$: try taking $\log(1-e^{x^3})$=$t$ and then use integration by parts 

(might help) @geocalc33

Comment: I found that this is: $$\frac13\frac{\partial^{-1/3}\beta(x, y)}{\partial^{-2/3}x\partial^{1/3}y}\bigg|_{x \rightarrow 0, y\rightarrow 1}$$ I don't know how to take fractional derivatives, though.